# Локальный сервер запускатся но нельзя на него зайти

Tags: python, django

Установил Django и создал проект. Пытаюсь запустить сервер. Он запукается но я не могу на него зайти.

В чём может быть проблема?

```
C:\Users\videx\Desktop\BaseSec2\BaseSec>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 06, 2020 - 00:11:49
Django version 3.1.4, using settings 'BaseSec.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не 8080, а 8000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сервер запущен по адресу http://127.0.0.1, порт 8000

У вас в адресной строке другой порт, 8080...

Попробуйте http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/550325)

Comment: @mkkik поясните, пожалуйста, почему вы указали, что данное сообщение не является ответом? Указанная причина вполне возможно является правильной.

Comment: @cauf потому что это вопрос - опечатка. Достаточно было простого комментария (который уже и был дан), после которого вопрос можно было бы удалить.

Comment: Нет, не достаточно. Вопрос задан. Он не признан "не по теме". Он должен иметь отмеченный ответ, каким бы простым он ни был

Comment: Дело не в том, насколько прост ответ. Дело в том, что это указание на опечатку. И вопрос и ответ абсолютно бесполезны для сообщества.

Comment: @mkkik нужно удалить ответ? ps читал ваш  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7486/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82/7491#7491

Comment: @Jack_oS на ваше усмотрение. Я высказал свое мнение, некоторые из участников посчитали ответ и даже вопрос полезными, возможно, его стоит оставить.